# Multithreading SslStream C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, ssl, https

I'm writing an https server which inherit from an existing http server. 
The Http server using a `ImprovedTCPServerSocket` which wrap `Socket` and when send/receive he is locking the scope as you can see:

```
public class ImprovedTCPServerSocket 
{
    private readonly Object m_SocketLocker = new Object();
    protected Socket m_Socket;

    public ImprovedTCPServerSocket(Socket mSocket)
    {
        m_Socket = mSocket;
    }

    public void Send(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
    {
        Socket mySocket;
        lock (m_SocketLocker)
        {
            mySocket = m_Socket;
        }
        mySocket.Send(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None);
    }

    protected int Receive(int requiredBytesToRead, byte[] receivedBytes, TimeSpan timeout, bool doReceive)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket mySocket;
            lock (m_SocketLocker)
            {
                mySocket = m_Socket;
            }
            while (some condition){
                currentBytesOffset += InternalReceive(mySocket, receivedBytes);
            }
        }
        catch() {
            .....
        }
    }

    protected virtual int InternalReceive(Socket mySocket, byte[] receivedBytesת int currentBytesOffset)
    {
    currentBytesOffset += mySocket.Receive(receivedBytes, // collect given input.
                                                currentBytesOffset, // offset.
                                                bytesAvailableToRead, // number of bytes to read
                                                flags,
                                                out socketError);

        return currentBytesOffset;
    }

    public virtual void Close()
    {
        m_Socket.Close();     
    }

}
```

Now in order to implement an https server I created a new class `ImprovedSslStream` which wrap `SslStream` and inherit from `ImprovedTCPServerSocket`
I'm using `SslStream` Do I need to do the same lock to `m_SslStream` as we made to `m_Socket` or is it ok to use it like this? 
Here is my code:

```
public class ImprovedSslStream : ImprovedTCPServerSocket
{
    private X509Certificate m_Certificate;
    private SslStream m_SslStream;

    public ImprovedSslStream(Socket mSocket, X509Certificate serverCertificate) : base(mSocket)
    {
        m_Certificate = serverCertificate;
    }

    public void Send(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
    {
        // 
        sslStream.Write(.....)
    }


    protected override int GetCurrentByteOffset(Socket mySocket, byte[] receivedBytes, int currentBytesOffset,
        int bytesAvailableToRead, bool doReceive)
    {

        m_SslStream=new SslStream(new NetworkStream(mySocket),false); //Do I need to lock it ? 

        try
        {
            m_SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(m_Certificate,
                false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
            currentBytesOffset+=m_SslStream.Read(receivedBytes, currentBytesOffset, bytesAvailableToRead);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {

        } 
        return currentBytesOffset;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your lock statement(s) for reading a readonly field `m_Socket` makes no sense to me

Comment: @SriramSakthivel edited it. `m_Socket` indeed does not suppose to be `readonly`, probably it is becasue the resharper.